# Titanium add multiple views to a scrollview at once?

Tags: android, titanium, scrollview

Is it possible to add multiple views to a `ScrollView` in titanium? So lets say I have the following:

```
var scrollView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView();
var views = [];

var view1 = Titanium.UI.createView();
views.push(view1);

var view2 = Titanium.UI.createView();
views.push(view2);

scrollView.add(views);

window.add(scrollView);
```

Would the above work? If not what needs to be done in order for it to work?

Comment: Yes it would work.... views = scrollView and all other child views to your scrollView... and finally add it to window.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-method-add) this shouldn't work. (Never tried before.) But you could do something like this:

```
views.forEach(function(view) {
  scrollView.add(view);
});
```

Comment: your example does work. But my only issue with it is that its not very efficient. Lets say i'm looping through 70+ times this will slow the phone down and make the app not very responsive. Total time to do this takes about a half a minute. So it looks like its back to the drawing board and come up with a different way to do this efficiently.

Comment: Yeah, i know in some cases Titanium is slow. Did you think about using a TableView? There you can set everything at once. This might be faster (especially if all 'rows' are equal in structure, like a twitter timeline for instance).

Comment: I was thinking about that but the views i'm using are highly customized. It would require more work and chaos to create a `TableView` than what i'm currently using. If only we could create more than one thread/process to use.

Comment: Highly customizing is no problem for Table Views. The question whether they are all different from each other or not. You can also fully customize table view rows.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but its the solution I used to this problem, hopefully its still helpful.  Basically, it involves setting the opacity of the scrollView to 0 until you are done loading.  This means that rather than the rows appearing 1 at a time, they all appear simultaneously, and that this can be run in the background while your program/user does other stuff.  Please note that it only works if the scrollView is empty - its not a good solution for adding rows to a scrollView that already has stuff in it:

```
var sView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
    //Whatever properties you need for your scrollView
    opacity: 0,
});

//childViews is an array of all the stuff you'd like to add to sView
childCount = childViews.length

//Add a postlayout event to the last childView - this will automatically set the opacity to 1 when the last child is loaded
childViews[childCount - 1].addEventListener('postlayout', function showScrollView(e){
    this.parent.setOpacity(1);
    this.removeEventListener(showScrollView);
});

//Iteratively add each view in the array to the sView
for (var x = 0; x < childCount; x++) {
   sView.add(childViews[x]);
}
window.add(sView);
```